# How to compute returns for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a data frame with in column 1 the dates and in columns 2 to 180 returns for stocks. I want to compute the returns for all stocks. I have tried for loops however cannot find the right syntax. Should I maybe use apply function? Help is appreciated.

my data looks like

| date | comp x | comp n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-11 | price x1 | price n1 |
| 02-11 | price x2 | price n2 |

Where the companies run from x through n and are in columns 2 intill 180. For all these companies I want to obtain the returns. Thus calculating ( price 2 - price 1 ) / (price 1). I have tried to do this by using a for loop and the Delt command. However, I keep getting errors. Is there also another way to do this? for example by creating a new dataframe?

Comment: Usually you would pivot to have 3 columns, date, stock name, stock value, then you would be abble to loop or apply much more easily

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your data, e.g. with `dput(data[1:10, 1:10])`? Also, what do you mean by 'compute' - the mean, total, by what - date, month, year?

Answer (score 0):

**colSums**

To sum up the columns 2:180 you can and store it in another column of the data.frame you can do simply:

```
data$totalReturn <- colSums(data[,c(seq(2,180))])
```

**rowSums**

If you want to get the sum columwise, you can use the function rowSums, e.g.

```
totalReturn <- rowSums(data[,c(seq(2,180))])
```

**dplyr**

If there are several entries (rows) for one day you should consider using the package `dplyr` and the functions `group_by`and `summarize` or the function `aggregate`.